# after i added a variable,the function stopped working

Tags: python

The function(hangman) worked before I changed it, although due to the parameters I input, it can't accumulate right letters.But after I added another variable letter_guessedright to collect right letters, this time, the function(hangman) can process but can't recognize the right letter. I only used the new added variable to replace the input of get_guessed_word and added an if clause to remove letters from available_letters. for other functions, I didn't alter a letter. But I'll paste them for readability.

```
import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"


def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r')
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = line.split()
    print("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist


def choose_word(wordlist):
    """
    wordlist (list): list of words (strings)

    Returns a word from wordlist at random
    """
    return random.choice(wordlist)


# end of helper code

# -----------------------------------

# Load the list of words into the variable wordlist
# so that it can be accessed from anywhere in the program
wordlist = load_words()

def is_word_guessed(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    for i in secret_word:
        if i in letters_guessed:
            continue
        else:
            return (False)
            break
    return (True)


def get_guessed_word(secret_word, letters_guessed):
    letter_str = ''
    uns_space = '_ '
    count=0
    for i in secret_word:
        for c in letters_guessed:
            if i == c:
                count=1
                break
        if count==1:
            letter_str+=c
        else:
            letter_str += uns_space
        count=0
    return (letter_str)


def get_available_letters(letters_guessed):
    import string
    av_lt=''
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if c  in letters_guessed:
            continue
        else:
            av_lt+=c
    return(av_lt)
letters_guessed=['e','i','k','p','r','s']
print(get_available_letters(letters_guessed))


def hangman():
    import string
    secret_word = choose_word(load_words())
    print("Welcome to the game Hangman!")
    print("I am thinking of a word that is", len(secret_word), "letters long.")
    print("------------- ")
    guesses = 6
    available_letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    letter_guessedright=""
    while guesses > 0:
        print("You have", guesses, " guesses left.")
        print("Available letters:", available_letters)
        letter_guessed = input("Please enter a letter:")
        if is_word_guessed(secret_word,letter_guessed):
            

> for c in available_letters:
>                 if c==letter_guessed:
>                     available_letters=available_letters.replace(c,'')
>             letter_guessedright += letter_guessed

            print("Good guess:", get_guessed_word(secret_word, letter_guessedright))
        else:
            print("Oops! That letter is not in my word:", get_guessed_word(secret_word, letter_guessedright))
            guesses-=1
        print("------------")
```

Comment: the changed codes are marked

Answer (score 0):

In your hangman function your **if statement** is **EMPTY**, which is due to python being indentation sensitive since no opening and closing brackets and so your code gives an error at your **for loop** line:

```
while guesses > 0:
        print("You have", guesses, " guesses left.")
        print("Available letters:", available_letters)
        letter_guessed = input("Please enter a letter:")
        if is_word_guessed(secret_word,letter_guessed): <----------

> for c in available_letters:
>                 if c==letter_guessed:
>                     available_letters=available_letters.replace(c,'')
>             letter_guessedright += letter_guessed
```

Fix your code up by indenting your for loop: `for c in available_letters:` so it links to the if statement to give you as shown below.

**RESULT:**

```
        if is_word_guessed(secret_word,letter_guessed): #your previous if statement    
            for c in available_letters: # <----
                if c==letter_guessed:
                    available_letters=available_letters.replace(c,'')
                    letter_guessedright += letter_guessed

                    print("Good guess:", get_guessed_word(secret_word, letter_guessedright))
                else:
                    print("Oops! That letter is not in my word:", 
                    get_guessed_word(secret_word, letter_guessedright))
                    guesses-=1
```

You also don't need to have repeated `import string` in every function, just at the top of your program.

Comment: this part is marked intentionally, in case people spend a lot of time to find where I altered. thanks for the string suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I didn't put the variables in function is_word_guessed in the right place. so even I got the number right, the if clause in hangman() didn't work